# Leaking Bucket with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to have an SQL query output the rows in a leaking bucket fashion?

Given a bunch of rows (could be a few could be a lot), each has a created_at column, the rows will be retrieved incrementally every X seconds ordered by their created_at, and starting from some fixed time (like beginning of the day)

So if these are the rows (created_at should be a datetime type, numbers here are to simplify the example)

```
**food, created_at**
apple, 1
orange, 2
banana, 3
meat, 4
brocolli, 5
tomato, 6
```

and X is 60 seconds, and the starting time is now, when the query is executed it will only return apple. after a minute it will return apple and orange. After 2 minutes it will return apple, orange, banana and so forth.

The idea behind all of this is to gradually release rows instead of everything at once, globally.

A more concrete example would be articles editted today in wikipedia, or pictures posted by your friends. You can consume everything at once, but I would rather do it incrementally for a fixed/user-specified time. If there is a better way to do this, I'd like to know.

Comment: datetime, I only wrote numbers to simplify the example

Comment: Why would you want to return the *oldest* items first?  Somehow, I think this t isn't a question about queries but about user interfaces.

Comment: Why would you do that? It seems like you're trying to move some business logic to SQL that shouldn't be moved there.

Comment: Use a `where` clause that excludes the unwanted rows? I don't understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @GordonLinoff *you* think it is about user interface. It is not. There is data I want to query it. Another example would be given 1000s of chat logs, I would want to out put each line in order (from the oldest) every second.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we start at `2015-09-27 16:00:00`, and the data in the table looks like this:

```
food     | created_at           
---------+--------------------
apple    | 2015-09-27 16:00:00
orange   | 2015-09-27 16:01:00
banana   | 2015-09-27 16:02:00
meat     | 2015-09-27 16:03:00
brocolli | 2015-09-27 16:04:00
tomato   | 2015-09-27 16:05:00
```

Then running this

```
select *
from data 
where created_at < timestamp '2015-09-27 16:00:00' + ((interval '1' minute) * X);
```

Gets you the first row with `X=1` (first run), the first and second row with `X=2` (second run) and so on.

If you increase the parameter X each time you call the query, this should do what you want.

Theoretically you can calculate X as `current_timestamp - "*starting time"*` (e.g. `current_timestamp - timestamp '2015-09-27 16:00:00'`) and then use "truncate" the resulting interval to the unit you are interested in (using `date_trunc()`.

Note that `current_timestamp` gives you the current time at the **start of the transaction**. So unless you are running in auto commit mode, you probably want to use `clock_timestamp()` instead.